# Lubuntu 18.10: how can I use the color schemes found in /usr/share/color-schemes?

Tags: lubuntu, themes, colors, lxqt

Lubuntu 18.10 uses LXQt as its desktop environment. There are some common features shared between KDE Plasma and LXQt.

One such feature is the presence of `/usr/share/color-schemes`.

In Lubuntu 18.10, there are a few color schemes available in `/usr/share/color-schemes`:

```
dkb@dkb-LXQt:/usr/share/color-schemes$ ls
Breeze.colors  BreezeDark.colors  BreezeHighContrast.colors  BreezeLight.colors
dkb@dkb-LXQt:/usr/share/color-schemes$
```

In Kubuntu, there's a GUI to select and even to edit color schemes. The GUI can be accessed by running

```
kcmshell5 colors
```

[image: GUI for color schemes]

and this GUI accesses **all** the color schemes in `/usr/share/color-schemes` and in `~/.local/share/color-schemes`.

However, in Lubuntu 18.10, the only GUI I could find lists only the *Breeze* scheme from the schemes available in `/usr/share/color-schemes`  as well as two others, *Windows* and *Fusion*, which are not listed in `/usr/share/color-schemes`.

[image: LXQt GUI]

And I couldn't find a GUI to modify even the Breeze color scheme. `kcmshell5 --list` doesn't offer `colors`.

So my questions are:

- can a Lubuntu 18.10 user use, for example, BreezeDark, since it's listed in `/usr/share/color-schemes`?
- is there a GUI available in the default Lubuntu 18.10 to edit even just the Breeze color scheme failing which can a package be installed from the repositories that provides this facility?

Answer (score 2):

Not only I am not aware of a such GUI for LXQt-only, but **I don't think the changes you mention (colors) will affect LXQT**.

I guess what you want is a pure LXQT, and **not** what I do, namely using the Plasma tool `systemsettings` (KDE System Settings). That might trigger a lot of kde dependencies (but that doesn't bother me, because I personally use a lot more kde than that, especially kwin and dolphin).

But even so, **if you do not use kwin, installing all those isn't worth it, and the changes you want are not visible in LXQT** it seems to me. The KDE/Qt Styles are shared by KDE and LXQt, but the changes you mention for colors, which I can make with the KDE Settings tool, are barely reflected in LXQT. What affects Lxqt looks is the style (the texture), the LXQT theme (mainly the panel) -  LXQT Appearance takes care of those two - and openbox settings for windows.  (On the other hand, when using kwin instead of openbox, changes in `kcmshell5 colors` are reflected by Kwin - e.g. you can have a dark Oxygen window theme).

If you do not want to install the KDE settings tool, but still want a lot more styles, try installing from repos more `kde-styles`, as they will then appear in the LXQt settings and can be selected from there. (On that, take a look at [Lxqt: what are the Qt-themes/Widget Styles, and how to install new ones?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/468709/32012)).

Even more interesting might be using Kvantum, a Qt themes manager which is not KDE-sprecific, but encompasses LXQt, comes with a lot of themes and has its own settings tool, Kvantum Manager.

[image]

Better install latest release from [here](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum) and avoid some bugs mentioned [here](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/issues/279).

For what it's worth, here's a glimpse of my Lubuntu 18.10 LXQt+Kwin with Kvantum-dark as Qt-style, KvSimplicityDark as Kvantum theme, selected also under `kcmshell5 colors`:

[image]

Thanks to your post I have realized that the setting you mention under `kcmshell5 colors` - or simply "Colors" under the KDE System Settings - was needed to have exactly the same color/texture in the window frame (a kwin setting) and the rest of the window (a qt-style setting). From that I conclude that the `kcmshell5 colors` setting only affects kwin and will not affect openbox, while the rest of the lxqt theming is not controlled from `kcmshell5 colors`.

On the other hand, Kvantum comes with a lot of Openbox themes which can be selected in Openbox Settings to mach the qt-style theme.

Comment: Thanks for replying and for the kvantum information. During much of 16.04, I used the Openbox session of Lubuntu and got really used to it. But after switching to Kubuntu, I'm quite at home with kwin. But I wanted to give Lubuntu 18.10 a fair look to see if LXQt, **as implemented by Lubuntu**, has any significant positives for me. At least for now, I don't see it having anything to offer me that I can't have in Kubuntu unless, as you point out, I add more "kde" stuff which, in a way, makes little sense.

Comment: @DKBose - well, I prefer lxqt to plasma for the very reason that what I liked in plasma I can have in lxqt, an *then* I think it even looks better, as I am not a fan of plasma looks, whether breeze or otherwise themed. Looking at my image above, the oxygen-themed window has larger and crispier buttons than in Plasma. Also, lxqt is significantly lighter than plasma, kwin crashed more often in plasma. But lxqt needs a lot more customizations to make it "ring".

Comment: @DKBose - I have to say that of late I have come back to Plasma5 as such (without LXQt). I suspect the Plasma-lxqt mix that I used was the culprit in freezes on my laptop when heavy loading internet browsers. On the other hand I do not like LXQt pure, without Dolphin, kwin etc. I have therefore installed Kubuntu 18.10 minimal.

Comment: I have Kubuntu 18.10 (with the kubuntu backports ppa) in a VM but pleae see https://askubuntu.com/a/1093955/248158 in case a bug I filed isn't fixed for those wanting to upgrade from Kubuntu 18.10 to Kubuntu 19.04 when the time comes.